# Is it possible to know who is the user that has last modified event by apps script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

Using Apps script, is it possible to know who is the user that has last modified event via Google Calendar API ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have good news and bad news. Answering your question *is it possible...?*. Yet it is! The bad news, you need a [G suite account](https://gsuite.google.com/) as it is described in these two places:

- [Calendar audit log](https://support.google.com/a/answer/6110475?hl=en).
- [do calendar events have audit history to show if event was modified after fact (even just via api)?](https://support.google.com/calendar/thread/1024126?hl=en).

Now, if you do have a G Suite account, then you can use the [Reports API](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/reference) to get the audits you desire by using the [Activities: list](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/reference/activities/list?apix_params=%7B%22userKey%22%3A%22all%22%2C%22applicationName%22%3A%22calendar%22%7D) endpoint. To enable it on your Apps Script project you have to go to *Resources* -> *Advanced Google Services* -> *[Admin Reports API](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/admin-sdk-reports)* and turn it on.